# elasticsearch multiple size options for multiple indices

Tags: elasticsearch

**My goal**: return 15 results for index1, 10 for the other indices

**My issue**: Since "hotel_name" is the most important field and it only exists in the first index, depending on the query, the response only has data from index1

**Request UR**L: "/index1,index2,index3/_search?size=25"

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "hotel",
      "type": "phrase_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "hotel_name^9",
        "country^8",
        "city^7",
        "destination^6",
        "state^5",
        "zone^4",
        "title^3",
        "description_short^2",
        "description^1"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Solved after @llermaly answer:

Post request on: http://127.0.0.1:9200/_msearch

Request payload:

```
{"index":"index_1"}
{"size":30,"query":{"multi_match":{"query":"hotel","type":"phrase_prefix","fields":["hotel_name^8","country^7","city^6","destination^5","state^4","zone^3","description_short^2","description^1"]}}}
{"index":"index_2,index_2,index_3"}
{"size":10,"query":{"multi_match":{"query":"hotel","type":"phrase_prefix","fields":["country^8","city^7","destination^6","state^5","zone^4","title^3","description_short^2","description^1"]}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set multiple sizes on a multi index _search query, but you can use the [Multi Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) and set different sizes for each index query.

```
GET _msearch
{"index": "index1"}
{
  "size": 15
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "hotel",
      "type": "phrase_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "hotel_name^9",
        "country^8",
        "city^7",
        "destination^6",
        "state^5",
        "zone^4",
        "title^3",
        "description_short^2",
        "description^1"
      ]
    }
  }
}
{"index": "index2"}
{
  "size": 10
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "hotel",
      "type": "phrase_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "country^8",
        "city^7",
        "destination^6",
        "state^5",
        "zone^4",
        "title^3",
        "description_short^2",
        "description^1"
      ]
    }
  }
}
{"index": "index3"}
{
  "size": 10
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "hotel",
      "type": "phrase_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "country^8",
        "city^7",
        "destination^6",
        "state^5",
        "zone^4",
        "title^3",
        "description_short^2",
        "description^1"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can use [Query Templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html#template-msearch) to avoid repeating.

Comment: Thank you @llermaly this has helped me a lot. I have added an example in my question.

Comment: you can then mark this answer as correct :)